# Associate a file with app

Tags: android

I would like to associate image files (jpg, png, gif) to my app. So when a person clicks on a jpeg file on their device it will either ask them what app they want to open it with, or open it with my app if that is their default setting. How can this be done? I can not find any info on Google other than user information, not developer information.

Any help is gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put this intent filter inside your activity in Android Manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.jpg" />
</intent-filter>
```

for every file type you'd like to open with your app.